# SQLite error in android studio project

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a problem inserting a row into sqlite database on rawquery of android studio project, that is multiple same rows are inserted at time execution of rawquery() method

`

```
public class Register1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    Button register;
    EditText name,mobile,email,password,cpassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register1);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,mobile_no varchar,email_id varchar,password varchar,flag varchar)");
        register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register1);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        cpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cpassword);
db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,mobile_no varchar,email_id varchar,password varchar,flag varchar)");
db.execSQL("insert into login values('name','mobile','password','type')");
}
}
```

`
above code is **summarised as the actual code** of my project.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new row into sqlite , you can use an object of **ContentValues** class . 
See below the example (Let's  consider that name, mobile , password  and type are the key attribute and login is the name of the table ):

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", nameValue);
    values.put("mobile", mobileValue);
    values.put("password", passwordValue);
    values.put("type", typeValue);

    long id = db.insert("login", null, values);
```